# Figma: Which other files use a component?

Tags: figma

In Figma, I'm cleaning up my files, and I'm interested in deleting a deprecated library. **How can I find out which other files use a component or a library?**

For a given file, I know that I can view which libraries it's using in the Assets panel. I'm asking about the opposite direction. Is there a way to do it from within the library, or do I have to open up every one of my team's files to check if its using that library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feature is only available natively on the Organization plan and is called Team Library Analytics: https://help.figma.com/hc/en-us/articles/360039238353-Track-library-and-component-usage

On the Pro plan, the closest option is to use [Instance Finder](https://www.figma.com/community/plugin/741895659787979282/Instance-Finder) plugin to find components used within the file. You can go through each file manually and launch the plugin in each of them to find instances. There are no automatic ways to do it.

Answer (score 0):

In the team account, you can set a file as a team library file. When you update that file, other files using this library will be automatically updated.